# RapidMiner replace numeric values in a range

Tags: range, rapidminer, substitution

Using RapidMiner Studio 6 have to replace the attribute values that are outside a certain range, 0, and I know that operator can use (or combination of operators). For example, if I have to attribute values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 and apply the operator for the range [3-5] I would be the values 0 0 3 4 5 0 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak Spanish but Google translate leads me to think that you need to change the value of an attribute to zero if it is outside a certain range. You can use the `Generate Attributes` operator for this with `if` in the parameters section.

If your attribute is called `a2` and you want to change it to zero if its value is below 3 and above 5, the parameters to the `Generate Attributes` operator would look like this.

`attribute name: a2`

`function expressions: if(a2<3,0,if(a2>5,0,a2))`